# Jquery - Get div number from a list by hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, count, hover

How can a get the number by hovering mouse over the div?

**HTML**

```
<div id="log"></div>

<div id="myList">

    <div class="divHV">One </div>
    <div class="divHV">Two</div>
    <div class="divHV">3 </div>

    <div class="divHV">Blub </div>
    <div class="divHV">Peter</div>
    <div class="divHV">6 House</div>

    <div class="divHV">last one is 7</div>    

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.divHV').hover(function()
    {
        XX = '';
        $('#log').html('This is the div number '+XX+' <br />');

    }, function ()
    {
        $('#log').html('');
    });     

});
```

**Working exmaple**
http://jsfiddle.net/9R4aC/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XX = $(this).index();
```

but that will start from 0 you can add +1 if you want..

http://jsfiddle.net/9R4aC/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.divHV').each(function(i) {
        $(this).hover(function() {
            XX = i;
            $('#log').html('This is the div number ' + XX + ' <br />');

        }, function() {
            $('#log').html('');
        });

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9R4aC/3/

Comment: I think the solution from Vytautas is much faster. Thanks for the fast answer!